# Como mudar a cor da ActionBar no eclipse?

Tags: android, actionbar

Estou estudando como mudar a cor da minha `ActionBar`, mas não consigo. Já procurei de tudo mas sem sucesso.

Essa é a minha `MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

E meu arquivo `style.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Este "colorPrimary" não funcionou -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_grey_900</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Veja [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#StyleExample)

Answer (score 2):

O ActionBar tradicional evolui para a utilização do Toolbar, que é muito mais flexível. Recomendo que você utilize os princípios do [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) e faça uso do Toolbar, assim você poderá alterar seu estilo de diversas maneiras, afinal ele é somente um View.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_sort"
        android:title="Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary_dark" />
```

Para definir o Toolbar como ActionBar

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Não esqueça de acrescentar em dependencies do graddle

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
```

EDIT: No eclipse você pode seguir estes [passos](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#) para incluir a libs

EDIT 2: Não mencionei aqui, mas você deve alterar seu Tema, removendo o ActionBar para poder utilizar o toolbar como ActionBar corretamente.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Obrigado tim ! Bom, acabei esquecendo de falar que es no eclipse que não possui gradle script. Acho que essa versão "Mars", já vem com funções do gradle integradas. Eu ainda nao sei atribuir novo " theme"ao meu projeto.

Comment: Olá Ralften. Eu não utilizo o Eclipse e não sei te ajudar muito bem nisto. Coloquei um link na resposta que deve te ajudar. Entretanto o conteúdo está em inglês. Boa sorte.

Comment: Blza! Estou usando no meu projeto a appcompat v7..que já vem integrada no projeto. Não sei se tenha haver, mas não tenho todas as versões de Android instaladas somente a API 21, API 10..achei que seria tão simples mas está sendo um pesadelo mudar a cor de fundo da actionbar..#chateado

Comment: Utilizar o toolbar é mais fácil. Faça isso. Também recomendaria você baixar o Android Studio, que está muito bom.

Comment: Acrescentei a edição que você precisa fazer em seu Tema para facilitar sua vida.